# XCode 8 No Devices Listed

Tags: ios, xcode, simulator

I don't have any errors but I just cannot run my app on my home laptop. I started a GitHub repo at school and ran some test there with no problems. When I cloned it at home I cannot select a device to run it on (There is only an option for a generic device). However, when I go to the devices window, I can see all of the devices there.

[image: Picture for clarity]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Preferences -> Components -> Simulators` and download the latest sim. You can also click 'Download Simulators` at the bottom of the drop down you picture.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error as you before. What I did is:

I change `General - > Deployment Info -> Deployment Target to 10.1`

Because when I use git, it changes my `Deployment Target` to 10.2

Answer (score 0):

I had to download the latest simulators and set the target to the correct iOS version.